# form posts it self, mail sends it self. is it google?

Tags: php, shopping-cart

i have a webshop running, and every couple days an empty mail is send, like an order. Is this most likely google?

I have a file called send2.php, it takes all info from session, all post data, and sends it via mail. after that it redirects to a "thank you" page.

Can and will google send empty forms just to see whats in send2.php? What would be the best way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why not check the server access logs to see what IP is hitting that script and then you can determine yourself if the IPs belong to google.  Its probably a spam bot though.  Esp if there is a form that links to that script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the mail your receiving is blank values as the values have not been set throughout the session then, why dont you check for those values before sending the mail, its true that the culprit is most likely a crawler, and many of them (inc bingbot) will not listen to a robots.txt file, plus a robots file is the first place a hacker looks for for info gathering.

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_SESSION['some_info'])){
    mail(...);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a file called `robots.txt` to your root directory and place this in it:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /path/to/send2.php
```

Keep in mind that this is not a perfect solution. This will prevent (co-operating) web crawlers from visiting your page.

**Reference**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

A better solution involves user authentication (ensuring that the agent prompting your script is not a bot).

Comment: Note: This will only affect **good** robots that look for and respect the robots.txt. There are LOTS of bots out there that ignore this setting.

Comment: what kind of user authentication would i need? Like server side validation? I only have javascript validation currently. Problem is, every email results in a fax, and my client is not happy wasting paper, and fax like that.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned there are a variety of way of getting around benign bots using `empty()` checks and `robots.txt`. However, these rely on the bots respecting your site. Many bots will attempt to inject values into the form (meaning an `empty` check won't work) and these bots don't care about `robots.txt` (I wouldn't be surprised if  `robot.txt`:`Disallow` actually *encourages* some bots to target your site under the presumption that you may have something sensitive... but that's just conjecture).

Your best best is going to be a "human-check". Either implement a [captcha/recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) solution, or some other logical test that's difficult for computers to solve or parse/understand before you allow submission: "What's this animal? [photo of common animal]", "Solve this simple equation [(12/4)+1]", etc etc.

These checks **will have to be server-side**. They generally involve setting a `$_SESSION` variable with the "answer" to the challenge task when the form is first loaded and then checking that the value they entered against this session variable once they submit the form. **Never** rely on Javascript to do validation for you (as you mentioned you are doing in your comment to x711Li). Javascript validation is purely done as a convenience to users (so they can see issues before they submit) or to reduce loads on your server (so you don't have to run/log lots of failed submissions). Any person or bot can bypass or manipulate Javascript validation, so make sure whatever method you end up using involves a server-side check.